# CakePHP - Duplicated Controller code and getting "Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate" error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I'm new to CakePHP and I've created a new website and baked all controllers and models. They work fine. I'm playing around with CakePHP. This CakePHP project creates a catalogue of website links under certain categories.

I baked a new controller called "LinksController" and I can see the View in the website. No issue there.

```
 <?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Links Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\LinksTable $Links
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Link[] paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
 */
class LinksController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Categories']
        ];

        $links = $this->paginate($this->Links);

        $this->set(compact('links'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['links']);
    }
```

However, if I create my own controller, with no baking involved, by adding a new file "FooController.php" directly in src\Controller\ and I would copy and paste the code from "LinksController.php" to "FooController.php".

I then change the controller name to "FooController". I loaded the webpage and got an error saying

> Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate.

It pointed out the source of the error. 
⟩

> Cake\Controller\Controller->paginate APP/Controller\FooController.php,
>   line 27.

Obviously, the error is in FooController and I'm trying to paginate the Links object as seen below.

If I comment out everything inside the index() function, I can see the view and there's no error.

If this code can work in a controller "LinksController", why does it not work in "FooController"? They are in the same directory and apart from the controller name, they have the same code.

I'm guessing I'm missing something and that you can't just duplicate the controller code?

Can you please help me out?

NB: There are no "Foo" tables in my mySQL database. "FooController" is just a custom controller.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Links Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\LinksTable $Links
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Link[] paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
 */
class FooController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
           'contain' => ['Categories']
       ];

        $links = $this->paginate($this->Links);

        $this->set(compact('links'));
       $this->set('_serialize', ['links']);
    }
```

Comment: 'There are no "Foo" tables in my mySQL database.' If you don't have a foo table you have noting to paginate. In fact you are trying to paginate $this->Links but foo is not related to links. The question is: what you want to paginate in you foocontroller? Do you actually want to paginate Links? So you have to tell cake you need to access Links table this way: `$this->loadModel('Links')`

Comment: Yes, I wanted to paginate Links in my Foo webpage. I'm new to CakePHP and I wanted to created a custom Controller.

Now I see that the Controller class has to have the table/model name as a prefix for the ControllerName e.g. you have a Links table, therefore name your controller as LinksController. It will have immediate access to those models as long they exists.

If you name your controller as FooController and there's no Foo model/table, your index function tries to access to a Links table an error will occur.

I used your suggestion $this->loadModel('Links') and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone interested, at this CakePHP page, https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

It says " In CakePHP, a controller is named after the primary model it handles". Basically, it means the entity or table.